# ASP.Net Datalist with linked DataSourceId does not reload

Tags: asp.net, datasource, datalist, multiview

I have a MultiView control which has a View in which a DataList is filled like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList6" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource11" Width="100%">
<ItemTemplate>
   <!-- rendering is left out to keep this sample simple -->
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The problem is that when I switch to another view of the MultiView control, to edit the content of this DataList and go back after saving the data, the data is not refreshed.
I have checked the database and I am certain that the data has changed.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DataList6.DataBind`